# How can this search bar fill the available space

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a search bar implemented in reactjs using react-autosuggest. Currently, the bar does not fill the entire width available to it and it looks like this.

I want this search bar to cover the entire top bar with the exception of the Sidebar Test "area".

[image]

The NavBar parent component which contains the search bar is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
import { SearchBar } from "./SearchBar";
export class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar className="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
                <NavbarBrand className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="/">Sidebar Test</NavbarBrand>
                <SearchBar tickers={this.props.tickers}/>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

The overall css for the application is listed below:

```
/*
 * Navbar
 */
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .form-control {
    padding: .75rem 1rem;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control-dark {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

/*
 * Search bar
 */
.react-autosuggest__container {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
}

.react-autosuggest__input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.react-autosuggest__input--focused {
    outline: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__input--open {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container {
    display: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestions-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.react-autosuggest__suggestion--highlighted {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/*
 * Utilities
 */
.border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
.border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
```

Comment: Your `react-autosuggest_container` should have a `width` of 100%. You have it set to inherit, which means it's inheriting it's `width` property of its parent, `navbar`. `navbar` doesn't have a width set either, so they both default to `width: auto`. Change it to `.react-autosuggest__container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: That moved the search bar to the left, but did not expand the box fully across the top.

Comment: Post your `<SearchContainer/>` component. The outermost div in that component is what should have a 100% width. Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Ah thanks for your edit, that changes my answer. Now all you should have to do is add `width: 100%` to `.react-autosuggest__input` as well.